# MVC C# Razor need to do load after post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using MVC with Razor.
I like to do the post first and after the post, do a load as in the following:

```
$("#stlist").load('@Url.Action("Kit","Spr")' + '?id=' +  '@Model.id')
```

As the post happens automatically, how do I do the load next?

Comment: What do you mean you want to do a load next?  Can you make this question more clear?

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking for and perhaps provide more contextual code to back it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna do a POST why don't you do a POST:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Kit", "Spr", new { id = Model.id })',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result) {
        $('#stlist').html(result);
    }
});
```

Also notice the *WTFish* `id` parameter concatenation you were doing that could be done directly with a helper.